# drop 0 from summed and grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I'm new to coding and will try to explain myself as good as I can.

I am working on a script to combine multiple excel sheets into one and sum up every value with the same discription into several groups.

Thanks in advance!

So far it's working out quite well, but the rows that serve as labels and have no values of their own are summed up to 0. I would like those cells to remain empty or have a placeholder like `'-'` in them. When I try `.replace[{'0':''}]`  or `-fillna(0)` I get `'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'`.

Also, if I put a placeholder in there before grouping I get the Error that it can't sum str and ints. 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str'

```
df = []
for f in File:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Excelsheet')
    df1.append(data)
df = pd.concat(df1)
df = df.groupby(['Group', 'Discription'], sort=False, as_index=False)['EUR'].sum()
df = df.sort_values(['Group', 'Discription'], ascending=[True, False])

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Excelsheet')
worksheet = writer.sheets['Excelsheet']

writer.save()
```

```
I get:
Group / Discription / 0
Group A / Discription A / 1000
What I'd like:
Group / Discription / 
Group A / Discription A / 1000
```

Comment: Which part of the code does this relate to? Can you make it a smaller example?

Comment: How do you mean?
The piece of code above takes an Excel and puts all rows in a list. Then groups and sums it up.

Every row has a group, a discription (account number) and the amount in that account. There are rows in the excel without a value in the amount column since they only serve to separate the groups.

Comment: which bit is the `'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'` ? can you remove all the Excel stuff and just get that error (with a toy example)?

Comment: I see what you mean. The piece of code I posted doesn't give an error.
If I put df = df.replace({'0':''}) after sorting the error appears.

Comment: In order to sum, these things "1000,00€" need to be just the number (not a string).

Comment: It is. The format is added later. I changed it .

Is there a way for the sum to ignore strings and only count the integers?